# tool to display patch file

Tags: diff, patch

What tools exist to display patch files?  A text editor is usually good enough.  [ColorDiff](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/) can add color.  Ideally though the tool would also show intra-line differences like KDiff3.

Answer (score 0):

Try the plain text mode of Pretty Diff:

http://mailmarkup.org/prettydiff/prettydiff.html

Answer (score 0):

If your using Gnome, [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) is what I use for viewing Differences / creating patches.  Haven't had a problem with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac OS X, PatchViewer lets you use existing GUI diff tools to view patch files:
http://appledeveloper.com.au/patchviewer.html

(Disclaimer: I am the author of PatchViewer.)